# Topological sort with minimum maximal distance in array

Tags: graphs, terminology, np-hard, topological-ordering

I have a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) that admits many possible topological sorts. I want to construct one that has the minimum maximum distance between a node and its neighbours in an array storing the nodes in sorted order.

Does this problem have a name that I can search (minimum maximum distance topological sort didn't turn up anything)?

(If the problem is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness), a good heuristic will do too.)

Answer (score 6):

The measure you are trying to minimize is called (directed) [bandwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_bandwidth).
Finding a minimum directed bandwidth ordering is [NP-hard](https://www.csc.kth.se/%7Eviggo/wwwcompendium/node54.html#4190).

Comment: Thanks! That's a huge help!